# Position and height of DIV

Tags: css, html, css-float

I sometimes get confused with divs when I try and build a little more complicated layout than normal.

I have made a quick example showing what my current problem is:

**EDIT: UPDATED jsFIDDLE**
Sorry, it's a little messy, but I'm just trying to get it to work. As you can see, I have forced a height on one of the vertical lines (but thats ok. that line is supposed to be fixed height). The vertical line I have problems with is the one between "Pictures for download" and "videos for download"

http://jsfiddle.net/GLjND/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

I have lots of div's, and I guess my problem lies within some parent somewhere, but I cant figure it out.

Basically I have a wrapper,and I have 2 areas of content. In this example, those are "first" and "third". 
The "second" is a vertical dotted line that I want to stick in-between these to areas, and the height of this div (which contains a vertical dotted image with repeat-y) should matsh the height of the wrapper, which in turn is defined by the largest of the two other divs ("first" and "third").

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.
http://jsfiddle.net/GLjND/3/ (the yellow background is just so you can see the new div)

Just give the divs

```
display: table-cell
```

and you're done.

Comment: table-cell breaks my layout. I will try and clean up my actual code and post it here so that you get a better view of what I want =)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. As you can see, the wrapper is now way to big (high). Also, it's not working on the vertical line between the "pictures available for download" and "videos available for download" divs. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/zan9X/4/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>

body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
}

#first{
    display: table-cell;
    width:230px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
}

#second{
    display: table-cell;
    background:white;
    border-left: thick dotted #ff0000;
}

#third{
    display: table-cell;
    width:270px;
    height:350px;
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using float property, i recommend you to set overflow:hidden to the parent div

```
#wrapper{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

And for the #second u have set the height to 100%, for this to work u should fix an height for the parent div

```
  #wrapper{
   height:400px;
}
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zan9X/5/)
Hope this will a good solution and will be more informative

Comment: Thanks, but the parent can have variable height, depending on how much content is in there..

Comment: no as much as i know parent div height should be fixed. and please vote up if u find this post usefull

Comment: But this is dynamic webpage. There can be a lot of content, so the parent div cant be fixed height. It has to be dynamic to fit the amount of content on the page.

Comment: <percentage> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

Comment: trying giving height:100% to the wrapper div. anyway height auto wont work!

Answer (score 0):

Just give the CSS property:

```
overflow : hidden
display : table-cell
```